# HighChat Heatmap: Tooltip

Tags: highcharts

An array of data points for the series. For the heatmap series type, points can be given in the following ways: [HighChart Api](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.data)

```
An array of arrays with 3 or 2 values. In this case, the values correspond to x,y,value. If the first value is a string, it is applied as the name of the point, and the x value is inferred. The x value can also be omitted, in which case the inner arrays should be of length 2. Then the x value is automatically calculated, either starting at 0 and incremented by 1, or from pointStart and pointInterval given in the series options.

data: [
    [0, 9, 7],
    [1, 10, 4],
    [2, 6, 3]
]
An array of objects with named values. The objects are point configuration objects as seen below. If the total number of data points exceeds the series' turboThreshold, this option is not available.

data: [{
    x: 1,
    y: 3,
    value: 10,
    name: "Point2",
    color: "#00FF00"
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 7,
    value: 10,
    name: "Point1",
    color: "#FF00FF"
}]
```

I have create a based on the example provided [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap-canvas/),

[image]followed is my modified
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ConnectRohitAt/g87ry6f3/) to show represent my data.

```
The things I want to achieve it.
1. Configure Data from Json Objects (Instead of CSV)
2. Currently 3 values are for a point i.e.( x,y,value) eg. 1,0,0.5
3. I want to add 2 more values ( x,y,value,name,color) eg. 1,0,0.5,"My Text","Green"
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It is not clear from your question.

Comment: @ewolden Sorry I have updated what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Use [tooltip.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) to format your `tooltip` string. I added json instead of csv also I have added extra data name, color. which reflects on tooltip.

```js
var myJson=
[{x:1,y:0,value:1.3,name:'a',color:'#fff'},
{x:1,y:1,value:1.6,name:'b',color:'#ccc'},
{x:1,y:2,value:1.0,name:'c',color:'#eee'},
{x:1,y:3,value:1.1,name:'d',color:'#ddd'},
{x:1,y:4,value:1.7,name:'e',color:'#yyy'}]


var chart;
 chart= new Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {
console.log(this)
            }
        }
    },
tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
       //console.log(this)
            return 'The value for x is <b>' + this.point.x +
                '</b> and y is <b>' + this.point.y + '</b>'+
                '</b> and name is <b>' + this.point.options.name + '</b>'+
                '</b> and color is <b>' + this.point.options.color + '</b>'+
                '</b> and value is <b>' + this.point.value + '</b>';
        }
    },

    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        margin: [60, 10, 80, 50]
    },

    boost: {
        useGPUTranslations: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts heat map',
        align: 'left',
        x: 40
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Temperature variation by day and hour through 2013',
        align: 'left',
        x: 40
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'number',
        min: 1,
        max: 12,
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 5,
            y: 14,
            format: '{value:%C}' // long month
        },
        showLastLabel: false,
        tickLength: 16
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}'
        },
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        tickPositions: [0, 6, 12, 18, 24],
        tickWidth: 1,
        min: 0,
        max: 23,
        reversed: true
    },

    colorAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0, '#3060cf'],
            [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
            [0.9, '#c4463a'],
            [1, '#c4463a']           
        ],
        min: -15,
        max: 25,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        labels: {
            format: '{value}'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        boostThreshold: 100,
        borderWidth: 0,
        data:myJson,
        nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
        colsize: 1 * 1, // one day
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: 'Temperature<br/>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e %b, %Y} {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value} ℃</b>'
        },
        turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE // #3404, remove after 4.0.5 release
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost-canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 300px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<!-- Source: http://vikjavev.no/ver/highcharts-demos/heatmap.csv.php?year=2013 -->
```

Comment: perfect as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way we can have the x-axis line on the top.

Comment: Option: offset is there to handle the positioning. But the value is causing the issue.

Comment: Plotline is there to have xaxis line. I want to know where are you facing problem for offset.